# SQL Create view or procedure in a SUM query without adding new column?

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, procedure, create-view

Supposed I have some sample data in `table_name_a` as below:

```
    code    val    remark   date
   -----------------------------------
1   00001    500    111      20191108
2   00001   1000    222      20191107
3   00002    200    111      20191108
4   00002    400    222      20191108
5   00001    200    333      20191108
6   00001    400    444      20191108
```

And I have a SQL query as below:

```
SELECT t.code, 
       sum(CASE WHEN t.remark IN ('111', '222', '333')
       THEN t.value ELSE 0 END) AS sum_123
FROM table_name_a t
    WHERE t.code='00001' and t.date='20191108'
GROUP BY t.code
```

Output as below:

```
    code    sum_123
   ------------------
1   00001    1100
```

Now I would like to create a view or procedure use above SQL query(Oracle), we don't want a new column, is it possible to let `sum_123` store into `remark` column? Supposed if I use below SQL query

```
SELECT t.code, t.value
FROM table_name_a t 
    WHERE t.remark='sum_123' and t.code='00001' and t.date='20191108'
GROUP BY t.code
```

and if I use above SQL query, my expected output as below:

```
    code    val        remark          date
   ------------------------------------------
1   00001    1100    sum_123          20191108
```

Is it possible to use create view/procedure save `remark` and `val` with `sum_123`and the `value/result` of 1100? Thanks so much for any advice.

Comment: So you want your view to display only one record?

Comment: Your first query is not correct; it'll return an error.

Comment: @GordonLinoff  Yes, I left the `group by` out, thanks for reminding

Comment: @Tejash I want that sum query to save into `remark`, then I can only use the simple query

Comment: So you also want something like sum_456 in your view? Or you want only sum_123 for different dates?

Comment: @Tejash Hi, yes, I also need `sum_456`, and also need to let one remark '111' save into such as `only_1`, `only_2`

Comment: You must edit your question and include expected output in detail.

Comment: @Tejash My question indeed included expected outputI am sorry, it was unclear, already edited again.
1   00001    1100    sum_123          20191108 ,

Comment: You need to mention that you need not only one record but also record for 456 and also only_1 etc to make it clear, so that experts can help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
select t.code, 
       sum(case when t.remark IN ('111', '222', '333') then t.value else 0 end) as val,
       'sum_123' as remark,
       date
from table_name_a t
where t.code = '00001' and t.date = '20191108'
group by t.code, date;
```

Comment: @Tejash . . . Not in Oracle.  Good catch.

Comment: @Tejash  I left the `group by` out, already updated, thanks for reminding

Comment: Just use `'sum_123' as remark`, then the `val` will be saved into `remark` with `sum_123`? I will try, thanks so much for the answer

Comment: @nullfearless . . . The names of the columns are just the aliases you assign to the expression.

Comment: Hi, `remark` The column of the database's table `table_name_a`, I am not sure I can use `create view` with this query, I will try, thanks again for help

Comment: Hey, I also need `sum_456`, and also need to let one remark '111' save into such as only_1, only_2, can I same code?

Comment: @nullfearless . . . If you cannot figure out how to modify this query, then ask a new question.  And yes, the query is compatible with a view.